# Download non-package assembly from URL using NuGet

Tags: .net, xamarin, nuget

As part of my build process, I'd like to have an assembly downloaded directly from a URL. It is not a NuGet package, but I was hoping there would be a way to specify it in NuGet anyway, just like it is possible in NPM to specify a URL rather than a known NPM package name. Is this possible and, if so, how is it done?

Comment: What build tools are you using? Just MSBuild?

Comment: Actually I'm using Xamarin. Not exactly sure what it's using under the hood. Just added the Xamarin tag in case it's relevant.

Comment: So you want a NuGet package to download an assembly? At install time? At build time? Is NuGet required? NuGet itself has no built-in support for downloading an assembly from an url. You could use PowerShell. You could use MSBuild, depending on what sort of project you are compiling. You could have a pre-build step that is run on a build server before the compile. However I am not completely clear on what you requirements are.

Comment: NuGet is a package manager, is it not? Therefore it downloads specified packages and their dependencies, does it not? What I'm asking for here is a way to specify the URL of an assembly alongside the names of any other required packages, and have that assembly downloaded as required just as packages are downloaded as required. *"NuGet itself has no built-in support for downloading an assembly from an url.*" That is an acceptable answer as it answers the question. Feel free to add it and, if no one begs to differ, I will accept it.

Comment: Correct and correct. A dependency for a NuGet package is another NuGet package. There is no NPM style support for depending on another assembly that is available to download from a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NuGet package can [depend on another NuGet package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies).

Whilst you can have a NuGet package depend on an assembly reference it must be in the GAC or part of the NuGet package itself. There is currently no support built in to NuGet for making a NuGet package depend on an assembly available to download from a Url without using PowerShell or a custom MSBuild task.